# Stored Procedure Returning Multiple Result Sets Not Working in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using WS02 Data Services Server (version 3.2.2) to genearte an oputput from a stored procedure which returns 2 results sets.

result set 1: the actual records returned from the query. 
result set 2: the total number of records returned.

I would like to aggregate both result sets into one XML output. I tried to use 'Output Mapping' options, but it is still not working.

Any help (inclusing documentation etc.) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this tutorial [Writing a Data Service to execute a stored procedure with WSO2 DSS](http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/09/writing-data-service-to-execute-stored.html)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, WSO2 Data Services Server doesn't support multiple ref cursors or nested ref cursors. There is a Jira[1] for this improvement.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-544